# Nonetype object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype

```
if (zlist[i+1])==(zlist[i]):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I get this error when I do this inside the function:

```
def plaintextmodOne(ylist):
    i = int(0)
    zlist = list(ylist)
    elementalcount = len(zlist)
    while i<elementalcount:
        if (zlist[i+1]) == (zlist[i]):
            if zlist[i] == 'X':
                zlist = zlist.insert(i+1, 'Q')
            else:
                zlist = zlist.insert(i+1, 'X')
        i += 2
    return(ylist)
```

If I just did `len(zlist)` in the while loop instead of `elementalcount` I get:

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I am trying to compare if the element to the left is the same in which case I add a Q if they are both X or an X if they aren't X.

They are added immediately before the repeated value. when the next iteration happens the index has gone up by two(as in by pair) to see if the next pair is the same.

Comment: FYI, you're going to have a separate problem when you fix the one I just solved; you're accessing `i+1` in `zlist`, but only verified that `zlist` is large enough to index `i` (even using the proper live `len(elementalcount)`).

Answer (score 1):

`zlist.insert` mutates `zlist` in place, and like most mutating Python methods, returns nothing (`None`). Don't assign `zlist` to the result of the `insert` call, because that throws away the reference to `zlist` the first time you do it. Just call `insert` without assigning the (meaningless) result.

Comment: wunderbar! i had not known this. I reverted to my len(zlist) back in the while conditional as well.

Comment: @jeslo: Yar, it's a general rule of Python design. Methods _either_ leave the original object untouched and return a new object resulting from the transform _or_ mutate the existing object in place and return nothing (the implicit `None` return when no `return` is used). There are exceptions for cases where the value returned is related to a single logical operation (e.g. `dict.pop` removes the provided key from the `dict` and returns the value previously associated with it), but the pattern is otherwise observed in general for all Python built-ins.